# What's the proper 'use strict' usage for IIFE

Tags: javascript, strict

I have a IIFE like this,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';


})();
```

When I use 'use strict' with this, jshint gives me an error and says possible strict violation.

Comment: The code as posted doesn't appear to trigger any warnings or errors on jshint.com - what other code do you have?

Comment: I don't think this would throw an error, there should be some more code...

Comment: When I paste that into JSHint it says nothing about a strict violation: *There is only one function in this file.
It takes no arguments.
This function is empty.
Cyclomatic complexity number for this function is 1.* I think your reduced test case has been reduced so much that the problem no longer appears.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Even if you add `this.abc()` or `alert(this)` within the function, jshint.com still displays no warnings etc.

Comment: @James, really? It should, since the IIFE is invoked without an explicit `this` (i.e. without `call()` or `apply()`), so inside its scope `this` will be `undefined` in strict mode. Maybe the behavior is different with function expressions, though, couldn't say.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yeah it does seem odd - I was expecting to see a warning when I added it